# Passing arraylist in intent from one activity to another

Tags: android

I have a class 'Product' and i need to pass the arraylist of 'Product' objects from one activity to another. 
I read that i can do so by making my Product class as Parcelable and use : putParcelableArrayListExtra (String name, ArrayList value).

In my app, i need to pass arraylists of objects from one activity to another. In this case, i need to make all those classes as parcelable and implement the interface methods.
Is this the correct way to solve the problem? Is there any other way to send the list of objects in intents?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the correct way is to use `Parcelable` or do the serialization to another kind of primitive object that you can put to Intent's extras