# how to send an arraList from one activity to another by using putExtra?

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

I have four different arrayLists,I want to use that arrayList values into another activity,I want to pass them by using intent.extra.So can anybuddy tell me how to do that.My arr7ayLists are as below:
**main.java**

```
completeOrderArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        productIdArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        orderProductIdArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        payeeKeyArray = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing arraylist in intent from one activity to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115199/passing-arraylist-in-intent-from-one-activity-to-another)

Comment: u can pass the arraylist by using parcelable class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in.putStringArrayListExtra` instead of `intent.putExtra` as

```
in.putStringArrayListExtra("complete", completeOrderArray);
    in.putStringArrayListExtra("product", productIdArray);
    in.putStringArrayListExtra("order", orderProductIdArray);
    in.putStringArrayListExtra("payee", payeeKeyArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, nextActivity.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("list", listObj);
startActivity(intent);
```

in next activity

```
stock_list = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("list");
```

Answer (score 1):

**Put:**

```
intent.putExtra("list_tag", yourList);
```

**Get from other Activity**

```
ArrayList<String> a = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("list_tag");
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first activity, use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, secondActivity.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("list_data", data);
startActivity(intent);
```

and in the next activity:

```
dataList= getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("list_data");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Intent.putExtra()` with `String`, `Serializable` parameters... or use static variables

```
intent.putExtra("extra", (java.io.Serializable) yourArrayList);
...
yourArrayList = (List<...>) intent.getSerializableExtra("extra");
```